# Retrofit 2.1 Posting Cyrillic Field Error

Tags: android, retrofit, postman, cyrillic

I am using `Retrofit 2.1`. But when I post a field that contains cyrillic word, it gives an empty response, however it should return 2-3 items. Here is the api:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("my_awesome_base_url")
Call<Questions> getQuestions(@Field(value = "rowsdata", encoded = false) String rowsdata);
```

And the rowsdata contains some cyrillic word that db should search and respond similar results. Here is an example `rowsdata`:

```
rowsdata = {"code":"-4","start":"1","where":"where  short_question like 'Вақт' ","end":"2"}
```

In the `rowsdata`, Вақт is in cyrillic, but it is somehow encoding it to some chars so that server is giving me an empty list.

I checked this on Postman, and it gave me the desired results, but when I send a request using Retrofit, it is responding like nothing is found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably an encoding issue.

From [developers site](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) :

> A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format in which
>   supplementary characters are represented by surrogate pairs (see the
>   section Unicode Character Representations in the Character class for
>   more information). Index values refer to char code units, so a
>   supplementary character uses two positions in a String.

Try [encoding the string](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) into UTF-8, make sure your file is UTF-8 as well (default in Android Studio I think).

Comment: how to "make sure" that my file is UTF-8 in Android Studio?

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/